# Change filepath and url during async chunk loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Does somebody know if it's possible to change the filepath and url of a chunk when it's loaded async by webpack? I know there is this webpack_chunk_load function which can be replaced by a custom one, but I only receive the chunkID, which is not enough information. To change the remote url and filepath of the chunk at runtime I would also need information about the imported module name or the webpackChunkName.

To give you a short insight why I want to change the filepath and (remote) url during runtime, here's my use case:

We have a big modularized web application with let's say 50 or more decoupled modules, which are loaded async when they are needed. For this use case, we need to re-build and re-deploy the whole web application with its core and all 50+ modules whenever a module's code has changed. To optimize this whole situation, my idea was to just build the core in combination with a single module and to offload the generated chunk to a CDN. During runtime, we could dynamically change the URL and filepath the chunk will be loaded from based on the import name or webpackChunkName. Thus, we are able to load chunks async even if the file mapping is missing in the hard-coded object webpack generates.

Does somebody have an idea how I could archive something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using the plugin at https://github.com/agoldis/webpack-require-from

Disclaimer: developed by me for that purpose indeed

Comment: Wow, that's pretty cool and sounds promising! Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm gonna use this for loading async chunks in a Chrome extension content script. Thanks for this!